# FIREBASE_TOKEN abruptly expired

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-distribution

We set up our CI to upload APK build to firebase app distribution using firebase app distribution [gradle plugin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/android/distribute-gradle).

We authenticate via the `FIREBASE_TOKEN` approach. We have been using the same `FIREBASE_TOKEN` for years without any problem. The last successful upload was at `2022-03-17T13:24 GMT+8`

However, something strange starting to happen since `2022-03-17T15:30 GMT+8`. We received the error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:appDistributionUploadDevelopmentRelease'.
> Could not generate credentials from the refresh token specified: The refresh token set as the environment variable FIREBASE_TOKEN is not valid
```

We resolved the problem by using a new `FIREBASE_TOKEN`, generated through the command:

```sh
./gradlew appDistributionLogin
```

However, the solution doesn't seem to last. The token seems to expire after 24 hours and the same error above starts to appear again.

We are currently exploring using the service account approach. But is this some hiccups on the firebase side? or could someone explain to me if `FIREBASE_TOKEN` is meant to last only 24 hours?

Appreciate for any feedbacks.

Comment: @Diainwater, we have since switched to use a service account json.

Comment: that's what I done same as you.

Comment: @YouQi How would this work for creating new projects. I thought service account is tied to a project. If we need to create a new project can I use service token from another project?